# Is "slightly different" a correct way to draw a comparison

Tags: grammaticality

Is it a correct, commonly used way to state that something is different, but only marginally?

> The night did happen but it unfolded slightly different.

Comment: [-ly?](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ly)

Comment: Slightly differently to what?

Comment: *slightly differently* sounds weird and incorrect.

Comment: "Slightly differently" is completely fine to me.  What is wrong with it?

Comment: If you are concerned about one -ly adverb modifying another, (which is entirely grammatical, if a bit of a mouthful), using something like "a bit" or "somewhat" in place of "slightly" might be more to your taste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Different**ly**, different**ly**, different**ly**...

Sorry, that missing adverb just bugs me.

I'm not sure what this sentence means, but grammatically, it should be

> The night did happen, but it unfolded slightly differently.

Note that "slightly different" is a perfectly good *adjective* phrase. It just can't be used as an *adverb* phrase.

> The third frog was slightly different [from the first two].
>
> The third frog jumped slightly differently [than the first two].

Comment: Why it can't be used with  an adverb phrase?

Comment: Because different is an adjective, whereas differently is an adverb. Adjectives are applied to nouns (e.g. frog), but adverbs are applied to verbs (e.g. jump, or unfold). So the frog can be different (or quick, or beautiful), but it jumps differently (or quickly, or beautifully). It would be incorrect to say "the frog jumped quick" or "the frog jumped beautiful", and it is just as incorrect to say "the frog jumped quick". Similarly the night can unfold quickly or differently, but it can't unfold quick or different.

Comment: @vehomzzz: I'm not sure I understand your question. Why can't *what* be used with an adverb phrase?